# Powershell invoke_sqlcmd is not closing connection

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I am using Powershell to a script to dynamically restore a database (sql server 2012).

```
set-location "SQLSERVER:\sql\$host_name\$inst\databases\.$db_target"
$db = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select type_desc,name,physical_name from sys.master_files where database_id=db_id(N'$db_target') order by type_desc desc "
```

When I execute the script I get the following error message :

> DBMS MSG - ODBC return code <-1>, SQL State <37000>, SQL Message
>   <3101><[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Exclusive
>   access could not be obtained because the database is in use.>.

I then use SSMS to make the database offline

```
alter database [db_target] set offline with rollback immediate
```

After this my script works fine.

Question :

1. Why is invoke_sqlcmd not closing the session?
2. Can I execute the alter database .... command from my powershell script?

Thanks

Comment: in your code did you close the connection like `$dbconnection.Close()`... Post the code so we can be of better assistance.

Comment: Perhaps connection pooling. Try `[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::ClearAllPools()` after the Invoke-SqlCommand.